# Use the AZ module in a non-interactive environment?

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-core, powershell-7.0

I'm hoping to be able to use the `Az` module to retrieve a secret from an Azure key vault, for use with a PowerShell script that has been deployed to a server and is run daily by Windows Task Scheduler.

Initially, I needed to follow the oauth (a guess) process:

```
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant '69a29f45-...'
```

Which redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/..., asking you to choose an account:

[image]

eventually, it indicates success:

```
Authentication complete. You can return to the application. Feel free to close this browser tab.
```

After this has been completed, the script that retrieves the secret works as expected:

```
...
$AccessToken = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyVault' -Name 'MySecret' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
...
```

I'm concerned that the token will expire, causing my script to fail.

The SharePoint module (`Pnp.PowerShell`) can [make use of a credential stored in Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-PowerShell/wiki/How-to-use-the-Windows-Credential-Manager-to-ease-authentication-with-PnP-PowerShell).  Can the `Az` module do so as well?

If not, is there another way to handle this authentication process without interaction?

Comment: Hi, any update on this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks we could not use `Az` module with the Windows Credential Manager, to use `Az` powershell in a non-interactive way, we always use a service principal, please follow the steps below.

1.[Register an application with Azure AD and create a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal).

2.[Get values for signing in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-tenant-and-app-id-values-for-signing-in) and [create a new application secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#option-2-create-a-new-application-secret).

3.Then use the commands below.

**Note:** Don't forget to add the service principal to the `Access policies` with the secret permission of the keyvault in the portal first.

```
$azureAplicationId ="<application-id>"
$azureTenantId= "<tenant-id>"
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "<client-secret>" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId -ServicePrincipal 
#get the secret
$AccessToken = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'MyVault' -Name 'MySecret' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SecretValue | ConvertFrom-SecureString -AsPlainText
```

Answer (score 1):

You can logon using a certificate tied to a Service Principal (SP) in your AD tenant. Then you just have to make sure that the SP has access to your key vault as at least a reader.